# Data View Customization in Extension

Tags: acumatica

I have overwritten the data view for a custom graph in an extension, which returns the correct data without issue, both by re-declaring the view, and using the delegate object techniques.  The issue is that when I do, the AllowSelect/AllowDelete modifications on the view in the primary graph stop working, once I comment out the overwrite, the logic works as normal.

Not sure what I'm missing, but any thoughts would be appreciated

Edit: To clarify, on the main graph, without the extension, the data retrieval and Allow... work without issue

```
public class FTTicketEntry : PXGraph<FTTicketEntry, UsrFTHeader>
    {
        public PXSelect<UsrFTHeader> FTHeader;
        public PXSelect<UsrFTGridLabor, Where<UsrFTGridLabor.ticketNbr, Equal<Current<UsrFTHeader.ticketNbr>>>> FTGridLabor;
```

And with the extension, the data is returned correctly from the modified view, but the Allow... do not work from the main graph, only when entered on the extension

```
    public class FTTicketEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<FTTicketEntry>
    {
        public PXSelect<UsrFTGridLabor, Where<UsrFTGridLabor.ticketNbr, Equal<Current<UsrFTHeader.ticketNbr>>, And<UsrFTGridLabor.projectID, Equal<Current<UsrFTHeader.projectID>>, And<UsrFTGridLabor.taskID, Equal<Current<UsrFTHeader.taskID>>>>>> FTGridLabor;
```

I have also tried the other process on the extension with the same results, the data is filtered correctly, but the Allow... commands fail.

```
    public PXSelect<UsrFTGridLabor, Where<UsrFTGridLabor.ticketNbr, Equal<Current<UsrFTHeader.ticketNbr>>>> FTGridLabor;
    public virtual IEnumerable fTGridLabor()
    {
        foreach (PXResult<UsrFTGridLabor> record in Base.FTGridLabor.Select())
        {
            UsrFTGridLabor p = (UsrFTGridLabor)record;
            if (p.ProjectID == Base.FTHeader.Current.ProjectID && p.TaskID == Base.FTHeader.Current.TaskID)
            {
                yield return record;
            }
        }    
    }
```

My main concern with not wanting to use PXSelectReadOnly, is that there is a status field on the header which drives when certain combinations of the conditions are required and are called on the rowselected events, sometimes all and sometimes none, and the main issue is that I obviously don't want to have to replicate all of the UI logic into the extension, when overwriting the view was the main intent of the extension for the screen.

Appreciate the assistance, and hopefully you see something I'm overlooking or have missed

Thanks

Comment: can you include some code samples for what you are implementing? It would help to answer your question.

Comment: Code samples added, any thoughts would be appreciated - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every BLC instance stores all actual data views and actions within 2 collections: Views and Actions. Whenever, you customize a data view or an action with a BLC extension, the original data view / action gets replaced in the appropriate collection by your custom object declared within the extension class. After the original data view or action was removed from the appropriate collection, it's quite obvious that any change made to the original object will not make any effect, since the original object is not used by the BLC anymore.

The easiest way to access actual object from either of these 2 collections would be as follows: `Views["FTGridLabor"].Allow... = value;`

Alternatively, you might operate with AllowInsert, AllowUpdate and AllowDelete properties on the cache level: `FTGridLabor.Cache.Allow... = value;`

By changing AllowXXX properties on the cache level, you completely eliminate the need for setting AllowXXX on the data view, since PXCache.AllowXXX properties have higher priority when compared to identical properties on the data view level:

```
public class PXView
{
    ...
    protected bool _AllowUpdate = true;
    public bool AllowUpdate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_AllowUpdate && !IsReadOnly)
            {
                return Cache.AllowUpdate;
            }
            return false;
        }
        set
        {
            _AllowUpdate = value;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

With all that said, to resolve your issue with UI Logic not applying to modified view, please consider one of the following options:

1. Set AllowXXX property values in both the original BLC and its extensions via the object obtained from the Views collection: 
   `Views["FTGridLabor"].Allow... = value;`
2. operate with AllowXXX property values on the cache level: `FTGridLabor.Cache.Allow... = value;`

Answer (score -1):

First check if your DataView should/should not be a variant of PXSelectReadonly.

Without more information my advice would be to set the Allow properties in Initialize method of your extension:

```
public override void Initialize()
{
   // This is similar to PXSelectReadonly
   DataView.AllowDelete = false;
   DataView.AllowInsert = false;
   DataView.AllowUpdate = false;
}
```

Comment: Code samples added, any thoughts would be appreciated - thanks

Comment: Can you remove Allow in base graph? I don't have your code so I can't tell if the Base graph is overriding what you're doing in the Extension.

Comment: Oddly enough, whether I have allow as true or false in the base, it doesn’t take effect when the pxselect is declared in the extension graph, the allows need to be in the extension graph

Comment: Yes this is what I recommended, is there an issue with that? It all depends on your Base code which I don't have. If you define View in Base then call allow in constructor, this all occurs before extension is loaded. When you load the extension, it redefines the view, allowed property were tied to base view, base view is discarded when extended. If in Base you had your Allow in RowSelected event handler, it would work because RowSelected of Base is called after View is redefined in Extension.

Comment: If allow in base constructor order is: 1. Create Base DataView 2. Set Allow on Base DataView. 3. Replace Base DataView by Extension DataView, therefore discarding any property change of base DataView like Allow.

Comment: If in base you have allow in RowSelected event handler of the DataView DAC the order is: 1. Create Base DataView. 2. Replace Base DataView by Extension DataView. 3. Base RowSelected is called and Allow will apply to the overridden DataView.

Comment: Based on your last post, numbers one and two are good, the view is overridden, but when I call the base row selected event from the extension, the allow properties don’t apply, they need to be called again in the extension.  In your opinion, should I need to duplicate the UI changes in the extension when I redeclare the view?

Comment: I'm out of idea and based on your feedback this sounds like the only way to go because everything else is not working.